# Naming your website longname.com vs shortcatchy.net vs shortcatchy.info

Tags: seo, top-level-domains, branding

I'm designing a website that will basically be a social network for sharing information.

I have the domain `$$$$d.net` and the same domain `$$$$d.info`
where "$$$$" is a word (that runs into the d) pertaining to the purpose of the site .

The `.com` of this domain was already taken, but they've got nothing showing.
They are also not ranked in Google.  There is only an error showing.  They don't seem to be trying to sell it either.

I also have the long name of the site `$$$$------&&&&&&&&&.com`
where the words "$$$$" and "&&&&&&&&&" would contribute relevant SEO to the site.
In fact the word "$$$$------" would also work if a one letter spelling mistake is recognized at all by Google, which I doubt but am unsure about. But as a brandname the "$$$$------" word still works relevantly.

Which do you think is a better choice to use?

- The **short catchy name** with the `.info` for relevance to information
- The `.net` which is **more familiar** than `.info` but slightly less relevant maybe.  (But I think "net" as in "network" still works because as I said, it will be a  social networking site.)
- The **long, `.com` domain** which has more SEO plus a pun, albeit on a spelling mistake.

I know its kind of a subjective question and also hard to answer without knowing the name (which I've obfuscated because I'm only in initial design stage)
but nevertheless I'm interested in what some of you guys think.

Comment: I say the .net because it's most important to your users in the end: Google robots don't care about social networking.

Comment: thanks ionfish this is what i was leaning towards. as a seo/webs newbie i appreciate the validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said .com of your choice already taken and it is  not in use( or error ( under construction  ) . so you can look for .net .info etc without any problem because the .com is not working properly you can easily overtake that domain in Google search engine. Or  for SEO  this makes no difference provided .com website ranks higher than yours. ( if you google  your website name " abcd" your website abcd.info will be shown ahead of abcd.com ( as this domain website is not active )

or

try to change the name little by adding words like (my) myabcd.com ,  (info) abcdinfo.com etc try the combinations choose best one suits your need

Comment: thanks for your answer panindra, i will definately look at mydomain.com otherwise i will go with either the .net or .info and not the longname.com

Comment: thanks to your suggestion to continue looking, i just purchased a domain im very happy with that has the best of all worlds, $$$$@@@@.com
It was a premium domain sale at godaddy, but still in my budget.

Comment: @jskye Best Wishes To Your website